# Clonezilla error creating image from encrypted SSD: LUKS header file not found

Tags: ubuntu, disk-image, clonezilla, luks

I'm trying to create a full-disk image with Clonezilla *alternative stable - 20221103-kinetic* (Ubuntu-based) of my Dell XPS 15 7590. The notebook has only Ubuntu 22.04, standard partitioning.

The disk of the PC is full-disk encrypted via the standard Ubuntu setup procedure (LUKS on LVM). Just to make sure that we are on the same page: THE WHOLE DISK is encrypted, so I'm asked for the password as soon as I turn on the PC, even before the boot starts.

Since the disk has a capacity of 512 GB but just about 114 GB are in use, I've chosen the "open it" option, so I can prevent the sector-by-sector approach and prevent the image from being 512 GB

[image]

Later on, I'm asked for the disk encryption password. If I provide a wrong password, the error is detected and I'm asked to retry. So I'm sure the encryption password I provided is correct.

Then the procedure starts. The disk size shown is the expected one (114 GB over 512 GB capacity) and everything seems to proceed

[image]

But after the operation is completed, I get this error: **LUKS header file not found**

[image]

I already tried twice, with the same result. What am I doing wrong?